# How to determine if a cell is empty in a .csv file?

Tags: c#, csv

I am trying to parse a column (File is composed of only 1 column filled with double numbers.) in a .csv file but C# throws me error when it encounters an empty cell.

```
{"Input string was not in a correct format."}
```

I want program to continue with the next cell when this happens. Is there a way?

Note: I tried

```
if(array[i] != null)
```

but this does not seem to work.

I use this block to read from .csv:

```
        var column = new List<string>();

        using (var rd = new StreamReader(@"pathofthecsvfile"))
        {
            while (!rd.EndOfStream)
            {
                var splits = rd.ReadLine().Split(';');
                column.Add(splits[0]);
            }
        }

        string[] arr = column.ToArray();
        double[] array = new double[arr.Length];

        //problem is in this block
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] != null)
            {
                array[i] = Convert.ToDouble(arr[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the file like? How are you reading it?

Comment: File is composed of only 1 column filled with double numbers.

Comment: Post the file... otherwise noone can help you.

Comment: There are many ways to read a CSV file.  There are libraries, there is your own code.  There are countless ways you could have written your own code.  You'll need to share how you are reading the CSV file.  Regarding your update: How are you populating `array`?

Comment: Rather than writing your own CSV parser, why not use a free, open-source library like this one from LumenWorks?  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Comment: you can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/

Comment: If you want to know what value is going to end up for a particular column that's empty all you need to do is have a file with an empty column value and see what gets returned from the code you're using.  You'll be able to see if it's null (it won't be) or if no, what it *actually* is, so you can compare it to *that*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check it when inserting:

```
if split[0] != null && split[0] != "" {
    column.Add(splits[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not validating the data you are loading into the array to see if it is in a valid format - `Convert.ToDouble` will fail for a number of reasons other than just `null` value and `empty` string.
If you are happy just to skip to next column, use a `TryParse` instead in the `for` loop:

```
double.TryParse(arr[i], out array[i]);
```